# Why Tomcat not accessible from another network?

Tags: tomcat

I m new with tomcat, I have a problem that i have installed Tomcat on my server machine at port 8983 now when from another network i want to access tomcat admin page using ServerIP:Port# then browser just error page like connection timeout what is the reason to this. should I do some firewall settings at server if yes then what are these settings?

Comment: Impossible to answer. You need to add at least some details about your server setup and network configuration. Which OS, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you ping ServerIP, from 'another network'?
If yes then probably firewall is blocking access on this port.
If no, set up your network correctly.